# Access Detailed Information From Anchor Tags On A Web Page

Tags: python, selenium, csv, web-scraping

I am scraping a web page, I have managed to fetch the data from the table into a csv file using selenium. What I am struggling with is to fetch information from anchor tags present on each row of the table.

I have tried clicking all the anchor tags of the table in order to get information from the corresponding URL's but it stops after clicking the first URL. It gives an error saying Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document.
I am not sure that it is the right approach to this problem.
Here's my code for what I have tried so far. I am sorry if the code is not properly formatted I am new to python and stackoverflow.

```
 import csv
 import requests
 import time
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

 browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\jewel\chromedriver.exe")
 browser.get(('https://e-sourcingni.bravosolution.co.uk/web/login.shtml'))
 signInButton = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".only")
 signInButton.click()
 time.sleep(5)
 table = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".list-table")

 for a in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".detailLink"):
  a.click()
  time.sleep(2)
  browser.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
  time.sleep(2)

 with open('output.csv', "w") as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerow(["S.No","Status","Organization","Project Title","First Publishing Date","Work Category","Listing Deadline"])
  for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
    writer.writerow([d.text for d in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')])


 browser.close()
```

What I need is to fetch the data from href of  tags having class detailLink. I cannot get to a proper approach to carry this out.

Comment: Are you trying to capture url value of all the anchor tags or hyper links?

Comment: There is further detail about the row present in the anchor tag. I want to fetch that too. But the href="#hf" in  the anchor tags and a javascript is executed on click of the url which holds the value of the URL.

Comment: I am looking into you script.I will add my answer soon

Comment: I have added my answer. Please check and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used normal for loop to iterate the table instead of for each loop. Try this and let me know how it goes.

```
import csv
import time
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

browser.execute_script("window.open('about:blank','tab1');")
browser.switch_to.window("tab1")
browser.get(('https://e-sourcingni.bravosolution.co.uk/web/login.shtml'))
signInButton = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".only")
signInButton.click()
time.sleep(5)
table = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".list-table")
links=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".detailLink")
for i in range(len(links)):
    links=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".detailLink") 
    links[i].click()
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
    time.sleep(2)

with open('output.csv', "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["S.No","Status","Organization","Project Title","First Publishing Date","Work Category","Listing Deadline"])
    table=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='list-table']//tr")
    for row in range(len(table)):
        x=[]
        for d in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='list-table']//tr["+str(row)+"]//td"):
            x.append(d.text.encode('utf-8'))
        writer.writerow(x)


browser.close()
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid b' in prefix of the string caused due to utf-8 encoding. I have fetched data from the links we are iterarting through and if remove I the encoding it gives an error UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 184: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Have you tried my code? It worked without any issues. I am using ```d.text.encode('utf-8')``` to encode the string. Please check and let me know.

Comment: @PrakharSood The above works perfectly for me. Please try and let me know

Comment: Yes it works thanks! Can you please help me with one thing? I need to scrape 'Published Notices' from the page we are iterating through. It has href="#fh" but has another URL underneath which I am not able to find.

Comment: @PrakharSood where i can find 'Published Notices' field. Please give me exact url. I will have a look. Also give upvote for my answer if it helped you really. Thanks

Comment: https://e-sourcingni.bravosolution.co.uk/esop/toolkit/opportunity/opportunityDetail.do?opportunityId=44011&oppList=CURRENT
I need to get the actual URLs hidden in here and add a column to the csv in the code.
I already upvoted your answer as it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes since you move to the next page it couldn't able to find the element on the previous page since you changed the page.
You can try this

```
import csv
import requests
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

 browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\jewel\chromedriver.exe")

browser.execute_script("window.open('about:blank','tab1');")
browser.switch_to.window("tab1")
browser.get("https://e-sourcingni.bravosolution.co.uk/web/login.shtml")
signInButton = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".only")
signInButton.click()
time.sleep(5)
table = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".list-table")

for a in table.find_elements_by_tag_name("a"):
    try:
        if a.get_attribute("class") == "detailLink":
            id = a.get_attribute("onclick")
            id = id.replace("javascript:goToDetail('","")
            id = id.replace("', '02260');stopEventPropagation(event);", "")
            a_href = a.get_attribute("href")
            browser.execute_script("window.open('about:blank','tab2');")
            browser.switch_to.window("tab2")
            browser.get("https://e-sourcingni.bravosolution.co.uk/esop/toolkit/opportunity/opportunityDetail.do?opportunityId="+ id +"&oppList=CURRENT")

            time.sleep(2)
            #wait for the element to load

            browser.switch_to.window("tab1")
            # print("in it ")
    except:
        print("detailLink is not present in the a tag class")

with open('output.csv', "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["S.No","Status","Organization","Project Title","First Publishing Date","Work Category","Listing Deadline"])
    for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
        writer.writerow([d.text for d in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')])


browser.close()
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my problem. This code keeps refreshing the main page in a new tab. What I want is to gather information from the href of the <a> tags having class detailLink.

Comment: @PrakharSood Please have a look at the code now i just edited it and let me know

Comment: Great, it iterates through these pages. Any idea on how I could fetch data from these pages and combine it with the csv below? Thanks for your help.

Comment: what fields do you want to fetch from this page ?

Comment: the ones with the class form_question as heading and with the class as form_answer as row.

Comment: just add the code above the `browser.switch_to.window("tab1")`

CODE :
`form_container = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".form_container")
            for container in form_container:
                con = container.text
                print(con)`